# ImportError: cannot import name 'deque' from 'collections' how to clear this?

Tags: python-3.x

I have get

> ImportError: cannot import name 'deque' from 'collections'

How to resolve this issue? I have already changed module name (the module name is `collections.py`) but this is not worked.

Comment: Could you perhaps include what code is giving you trouble or, even better, craft a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when i run the command `python -m venv <env folder>`. Renamed my file from: collections.py **to** my_collections.py.
It worked!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to change my import statement to

```
from collections import deque
```

and previously it was

```
 from collections import Deque
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to rename my python file from keyword.py to keyword2.py.